# A signature in MetricsSystem.class refers to term servlet

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to register a custom `Spark` metrics source to Spark metrics system with following code:

```
val source = new CustomMetricSource()
SparkEnv.get.metricsSystem.registerSource(source)
```

Then the code failed compiling with following error:

> Error:scalac: Error: bad symbolic reference. A signature in MetricsSystem.class refers to term servlet
>   in value org.jetty which is not available.
>   It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MetricsSystem.class.
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad symbolic reference. A signature in MetricsSystem.class refers to term servlet
>   in value org.jetty which is not available.
>   It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
>   the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling MetricsSystem.class.
>       at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.toTypeError(UnPickler.scala:847)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef.complete(UnPickler.scala:854)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan$LazyTypeRef.load(UnPickler.scala:863)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.typeParams(Symbols.scala:1489)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$transform$SpecializeTypes$$normalizeMember$1.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:798)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anonfun$scala$tools$nsc$transform$SpecializeTypes$$normalizeMember$1.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:798)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.atPhase(SymbolTable.scala:207)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.beforePhase(SymbolTable.scala:215)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes.scala$tools$nsc$transform$SpecializeTypes$$normalizeMember(SpecializeTypes.scala:797)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anonfun$22.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:751)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes$$anonfun$22.apply(SpecializeTypes.scala:749)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes.specializeClass(SpecializeTypes.scala:749)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.SpecializeTypes.transformInfo(SpecializeTypes.scala:1172)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.InfoTransform$Phase$$anon$1.transform(InfoTransform.scala:38)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.rawInfo(Symbols.scala:1321)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1241)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.isDerivedValueClass(Symbols.scala:658)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.isMethodWithExtension(Symbols.scala:661)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.preEraseNormalApply(Erasure.scala:1100)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.preEraseApply(Erasure.scala:1195)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.preErase(Erasure.scala:1205)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1280)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1030)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1235)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1233)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2936)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:34)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:28)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:19)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1232)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2897)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:48)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1288)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1030)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2927)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2925)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2925)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1276)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2897)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.scala$tools$nsc$transform$TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$1.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2936)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:34)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1292)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1030)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2904)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1280)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1279)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2936)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:34)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:28)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:19)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1278)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2897)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:48)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1292)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1030)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2927)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(Trees.scala:2925)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformStats(Trees.scala:2925)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1298)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1298)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2936)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:34)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:28)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:19)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1297)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:13)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2897)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.scala$tools$nsc$transform$TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$super$transform(TypingTransformers.scala:44)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:46)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(TypingTransformers.scala:46)
>       at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2936)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.atOwner(TypingTransformers.scala:34)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.TypingTransformers$TypingTransformer.transform(TypingTransformers.scala:46)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anon$1.transform(Erasure.scala:1292)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:1302)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:888)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:227)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:464)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:431)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:431)
>       at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:431)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1583)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1557)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1553)
>       at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1662)
>       at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:115)
>       at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:94)
>       at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:22)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:101)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:47)
>       at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:29)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:26)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

The IDE I'm using is Jetbrains IntelliJIDea 15 CE.

I'm suspecting it's classpath issue but not sure how to further debug.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a jetty dependency e.g. for sbt `"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "8.1.18.v20150929"`